# Vue / typescript: eslint variables in the template tag

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I'm trying to get ESLint with typescript to properly lint the code inside the  tags in .vue files. But there are no errors displayed for using undefined variables, I can't seem to figure out why or how to enable this behavior.

Example:

```
//home.vue

<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    {{ object.does.not.exist.should.display.lint.error }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Comment: It'd definitely be a nice to have. But doesn't look like it's possible ATM or coming anytime soon according to this https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/98

Comment: @Miguel actually it is possible with veture (https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/interpolation.html)! It is an experimental feature but I have now used it for 8 months, works fairly well. There are some issues such as that all methods needs to have a return type explicitly defined or you will get some weird errors, in other parts of the code that are unrelated to the actual issue.

Comment: Just had a play, looks awesome; thanks for sharing!